# How to load another .so file in your android project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Our library should be created outside of our project and it should be called with in our project from outside? please give any suggestion."I already know how to create so file and all.But not able to call that .so file into a different android project".please help me..

Comment: As far as i understand you have to have jni binding with your library(.so file) from java. In usual case you should create a jar library file along with your .so library.

Comment: thanks,i tried this but its still showing error,could you pls elaborate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195426/re-use-code-android-ndk/20044261#20044261),

> "I already know how to create so file and all.But not able to call that .so file into a different android project"

In another project, you should :

> 1 - Add folder jni/libs/*.so
>
> 2 - Use "Right-click mouse" -> Android Tools -> Add native support -> Set name of file *.cpp
>
> 3 - Two files : *.cpp and Android.mk appeared.
>
> 4 - Use Cygwin to build & compile *.so into the project.

[image]

p/s :

- **You should also define content in the file Android.mk exactly before built.**
- **Application.mk is used to build to which folder**.
- **APP_PLATFORM also important too, should define exactly.**

Follow this image for more details, about the result.

[image]

Thanks,

p/s : **When you have done, you can call file **.so* from folder *jni*** by using the following code :

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
}
```

**DOWNLOAD .so FILE**

[It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732174/android-ffmpeg-so-download) is where do you can download .so file while executing FFMPEG.

Comment: I tried but is not showing any .so file to be selected from choose file option...

Comment: Sorry about not enough information. I will edit my answer

Comment: hi alex how to exeucte command using your update ffmpeg.so file(https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtlieuxn5e5xzve/ffmpeg.so) Plz help . i m tried but getting error exit value -4 error

Comment: [How to build ffmpeg](https://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk)

Comment: Can please provide .so file for executing FFMpeg command in my android app.

Comment: @ButaniVijay Already edit the answer, please check again. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have NDK can i directly use .so file in my project like adding .so file in libs folder

Comment: Unable to download prebuilt .so file as you suggested

Comment: You don't know which link? http://www.mediafire.com/download/81luapelsre53fl/ffmpeg.so

Comment: don't have NDK can i directly use .so file in my project like adding .so file in libs folder.

Comment: Never try before. You can try?

Comment: @HuyTower I don't understand the command screenshot you have given here? Can you explain exactly how to use or write this command? I am confused here and can't seem to move forward here. Also, I am trying to find the option you suggested in step 2. I can't seem to find that option. Sorry I am new to development and trying to develop an application that has size issues due to Writing Minds library for FFMpeg

Comment: @Kartik : Ah you need find out about ndk first, then you know which things need to build into *.so file as the answer.

Comment: The answer is is very old, not applicable in android studio.